# Why can't I use the typescript transpiled javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, module

**I am learning TypeScript and the code that I transpiler cannot use because of an error in the html, it is this:**

[image: Error in console]

I'm trying to use transpiled code on my html

**html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
<script type="module" src="./dist/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**my directory:**

[image: Directory]

**package.json:**

```js
{
  "name": "ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
     "moduleResolution": "classic",                       
     "outDir": "./dist",  
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,          
    "strict": true,                                    
    "skipLibCheck": true                               
  }
}
```

As you can see is very simple but I don't really understand why I can't, I search for a time and I saw something about module loaders, and build tools, but I don't catch it, and I don't know how implement them.

Comment: If you want to use ES6 modules in your html, don't use `"target":"es5"` in your compiler options. Also [set the `"module"` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)!

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, this actually works, i only want more compatibility with old browsers to my projects